# Issues with setGame

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to force my bot to change it's "Game" when it startes to "!help for help" but cannot seem to get it work.

Currently my code is...

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const Request = require('request');
const Bot = new Commando.Client();

Bot.client.setGame("!help for help");
```

I've also tried...

```
Bot.client.setStatus("!help for help");
Bot.user.setGame("!help for help");
Bot.user.setStatus("!help for help");
```

I use can't seem to understand how you call to this to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.user.setGame("use !help");
});
```

Comment: This upsets me... I tried setGame("") within the ready check... But this works really well.

Comment: If you have further questions, I suggest you check out the Discord API server: https://discordapp.com/invite/discord-api and visit the channel for your library.

Comment: setGame is deprecated, use setActivity.

Answer (score 0):

When checking if your client is ready, you can add in this little piece of code.

```
Client.user.setActivity(" your game here "):
```

Hope this helped!